# CSS floating 2 column layout with multiple elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to create a simple two-column layout using four divs. I am restricted and cannot modify the HTML structure. I only can modify the CSS.

I want the second div in the right column to fall directly below the previous right column div. Right now, it pushes to the top of the second left div.

Right now this is what I have in HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="left">
        Left 1
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right 1
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        Left 2
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right 2
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
  height: 400px;
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.right {

  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
   display: block;
}
```

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lun61g7a/2/

Comment: I looked closer and can actually modify the parent's CSS, but i can't create separate divs for each column unfortunately. Ill modify my question to reflect this.

Comment: So I am stuck with a single parent encapsulating this all and can really only modify the CSS, not the HTML

Answer (score 1):

Use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and allow the elements to move to the next "row" when needed

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left {
  height: 400px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.right {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="left">
    Left 1
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right 1
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    Left 2
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks closer, but I actually want the first right div to end at the end of the content and the 2nd right div to begin right below it. It is still pushing the 2nd right div all the way down